# Set default rightBarButtonItem for UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uiappearance

Sup guys,

I have a tabBarController with a navigationController on each tab.

I wanted to set de default right bar button of navigation bar so I wouldn't have to write the same code on 3 different view controllers.

I tried `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setRightBarButtonItem:myButton];`

but had no success, is says:
`-[_UIAppearance setRightBarButtonItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Then I tried to create my own UINavigationController subclass so I could set the button like:
`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton` but again no success, nothing seems to happen probably because I dont have a navigationItem at this time.

Anyone have another solution?

Comment: You can't do that. It's not part of the appearance at all. If you have structurally common elements, create a common `UIViewController` subclass that sets up the right bar button item, then create your three others as subclasses of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inherit from the `UIViewController` you can set the right button like this

```
UIBarButtonItem * rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foobar.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
[rightButton release];
```